How to find the dos.library functions in an Amiga rom?
I'm disassembling Amiga Kickstart 1.0 ROM (NTSC) and looking for the dos.library code.
I'm sure dos.library is in the ROM since it's needed to use the disk drives. I also found this area:

(Symbols added by me may be wrong.)
So this seems to be the "rom tag" and "resident structure" of dos.library - but where do I find the jumptable/vector?
When you call into any Amiga library you jsr to a negative offset of a multiple of 6 from the library base in A6. It would seem that this structure is not the library base, or perhaps things get set up in RAM using this structure along with a constructed jumptable/vector?

I remember that dos.library in Kickstart 1.* series was written in BCPL instead of C, and it had a lot of oddities. I tried to patch one of the library functions only to discover that it had a non-standard jump table - instead of a series of jmp instructions, it had something else, although I can't remember what. In short, any expectations you have about "nomal" behaviour of an Amiga library may well not apply to dos.library...

The library vectors are normally generated at initialisation time from a (usually compressed) table embedded in the library. You can get at the table by following the ROMTag datastructures, but it's probably easiest to boot that Kickstart, find dos.library in RAM, and copy the jump table.
This is actually the only sane option here. When Bit 7 (AUTOINIT) of RT_FLAGS is set, RT_INIT is a pointer to a structure describing the library base and exec.library performs an autoinitialisation process on it. If it is not set, RT_INIT is a pointer to some code which does manual initialisation, which this version of dos.library has chosen to do. Perhaps it's because this Kickstart version predates autoinitialisation, or maybe it's because AmigaDOS is a chunk of BCPL bodged in where it doesn't really fit and it isn't following the platform conventions. (Consider this a warm-up for the many kinds of weird that you'll discover while disassembling it.)
For example, in FS-UAE you can launch it with fs-uae --console_debugger=1, hit F12+D to drop into the debugger after booting Workbench[0], and then do Tl to list the libraries and their base address. From there you can do m to dump memory such as the jump table.
What you do with that jump table is up to you. I'd be inclined to write a simple Perl/Python program to turn that raw dump and the FD files (a mapping of offsets to function names) into a symbol table to load into Ghidra, but you could even just load the raw binary jump table into Ghidra and tell it to disassemble that.
[0] You do actually need to boot Workbench, or at least a disk which has been Installed, and can't just break into the debugger at the Workbench disk prompt as dos.library is not yet initialised. This is interesting in its own right as it means that dos.library and the filesystem driver do not actually need to be in the ROM, and in an alternative universe could have been on the boot floppy instead. However because mask ROM used to be cheaper than RAM, there was little sense to do it that way.

Interesting! I didn't manage to get WinAUE working last time I tried but I forget why. I think I couldn't find a workbench disk and I wanted to play with AmigaBasic. Anyway I'll give it another go. I am now maybe even more intrigued about how to get at the tables by digging around in the ROM though.

AmigaBASIC?  The horror!!! :D

@Zenzizenzizenzic Back when I had my A1000 I never had an assembler or compiler but used to program Z80 machine code on my Speccy by writing BASIC programs that POKEd instructions into RAM. But I never made that leap on the Amiga. So I want to try it now (-:

Go fer it!  You could even try ABasic, but that only runs on 1.0 or 1.1
